# Multiple base classes for one derived class, inheritance in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, base-class

If I have a class with two base classes :

```
public partial MyClass : Base1, Base2 {


}
```

To call the constructor of Base1 I would do this:

```
public MyClass() : base(myParamForBase1);
```

But I need to call the second base class to get the base init value like this:

```
base.OnInit(e);
```

I cannot do the above of course because C# thinks I'm referring to Base1 not Base2, how do I resolve this? In other words how can I refer to Base2?

Comment: You can't have multiple base classes. You can have a single base class and infinite interfaces

Comment: The need for multiple inheritance always results `from` a poorly designed class structure. Post an example of what you need. I'm sure there's a way to structure it so that you don't need multiple inheritance (which does not exist anyways)

Comment: @HighCore sure, I'm converting right now believe it or not an MVC project to a standard .NET project for SharePoint. I can post my situation and it would be awesome if you could help me out

Comment: WHAT. Oh I see you didn't knew C# has multiple inheritance. You sounded like you were able to compile all of the above. I thought C# changed alot in newer version

Comment: @Ata lol yes, I apologize for my ignorance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# does not support multiple class inheritance. You can only implement multiple interfaces, and inherit from (extend) a single base class.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. I saw this multiple times, but just wanted to hold onto hope

Comment: @MyName, you might want to look at [the diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) for a reason why this would never work in c#.

Comment: @MyName You can, however, work with cascading inheritance. `Grandchild` inherits from `Child`, which inhertis from `Mother`.

Comment: @AndreCalil :( I tried the cascading inheritance first, but I had to make them one because I couldn't find a way to make multiple Page_Load events work.

Comment: @gunr2171 ty, here's a better link though for noobs like myself: http://nazar-merza.com/index.php/getting-started/74-the-problem-with-multiple-inheritance , it explains the diamond problem really well, the animal example I don't think was the best one but still a good resource

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, make a class that inherits from the first base

something like this

```
    public Base2 : Base1 {


    } 
    public MyClass : Base2  {


    }
```

Not that i like this, but it may help in some cases